# Combining two EitherT, return first if it succeeds else return second

Tags: scala, scala-cats, either

Consider the following snippet:

```
def foo(x:String): EitherT[F, Throwable, String] = ???
def bar(x:String): EitherT[F, Throwable, String] = ???
```

I want the following:

On some input `s`, first call `foo(s)` and if it "fails" return the output of `bar(s)` else return the output of `foo(s)` without calling `bar(s)`. I have come up with the following.

```
def foobar(s:String) = {
  val f = foo(s)
  // if f is successful return f else return bar(s)
  f.biflatMap(_ => bar(s), _ => f)
}
```

Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `recoverWith`:

```
foo(s).recoverWith { _ =>
 bar(s)
}
```

Many other error-handling monads have similar convention: `.recover` that takes error-type-to-success-type, and `.recoverWith` that takes error-type-to-whole-monad-type. Sometimes they are named `handle` and `handleWith` respectively. Method without `With` always takes pure value calculation, and method with `With` always takes monad/wrapper type computation.

Comment: Looks much better and works fine with Scala 2.13 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/X24pfKa1Qqy7gyTjzz2LLg but gives an error with Scala <= 2.12: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oTLzs9BLRmaLHZGZdCoV7w . The error is 
`type mismatch;
 found   : Throwable => cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Throwable,String]
 required: PartialFunction[Throwable,cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Throwable,String]]`

Comment: For 2.12 and before you have to make it a partial function explicitly - replace `_` with `case _: Throwable` and you are good to go.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kXhiVpQxQbC9DquHiMht7A making partial function also seems to give an issue with older scala versions. The new error is `could not find implicit value for parameter F: cats.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future]
not enough arguments for method recoverWith: (implicit F: cats.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future])cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Throwable,String].
Unspecified value parameter F.` :)

Comment: You are missing `implicit def ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` - see https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/f44f25136260d6e7e35c21ab4c1aaacc6b2fa7a2/core/src/main/scala/cats/instances/future.scala#L10

Answer (score 1):

Here's some implementations

```
  import cats.implicits._
  import import cats.data.EitherT


  foo("").biflatMap(
    err => bar(""),
    str => EitherT.fromEither[F](str.asRight[Throwable])
  )

  foo("").biflatMap(
    err => bar(""),
    str => EitherT.liftF(str.pure[F])
  )

  foo("").leftFlatMap(
    err => bar("")
  )

  foo("").recoverWith(err => bar(""))

  for {
    err <- foo("")
    x <- bar("")
  } yield x
```

I hope this helps